# multiple condition in store procedure sql server

Tags: sql-server

i want display data on grid with store procedure in two condition.

first, if filter is null or blank = result 'select * from division where isactive = 1'

and if filter is not null . i want select * from division where code like ...

and this is my query.what's wrong ?
please help to fix...

```
DECLARE @Filter varchar(100)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000)
SET @SQL = 'select * from Division'
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'where'

IF @Filter is null or @Filter = ''
BEGIN
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'IsActive = 1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'Code Like ''%' + @Filter + '%''' 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this below query will help

DECLARE @Code varchar(10)   --- Input parameter

DECLARE @IdFilter int = 0

```
IF ISNULL(@Code,'') = ''
    SET @IdFilter = 1    


select * from division WHERE (@IdFilter = 1 OR Code Like '%' + @Code + '%') and ISActive=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any spaces in your code, so after the second `SET` your query will look like this:

```
'select * from divisionwhere'
```

This is a syntax error. Rather than use dynamic SQL and fall into this kind of trap, try using this:

```
select * from division
where ((@Filter is null or @Filter = '') and IsActive = 1)
or (@Filter is not null and @Filter <> '' and Code Like ''%' + @Filter + '%'')
```